# How to increment the CSS Selector id?

Tags: jmeter

CSS Selector for the list view record.

## Contacts_listView_row_1

How can I increment the row by defining a variable?
(#Contacts_listView_row_1)

[image: CSS Selector Extractor]

Answer (score 0):

You can try and move to a library like SASS or LESS that support the use of variables. A different approach would be to use a selector that matches on attribute values. That would look something like `[id^="Contacts_listView_row_"]`. Hope it helps